# Blog section within wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, subdomain, blogs

I have a site and I'd like a sub section of that site to be blog.

Details:

The site is fairly dynamic.

I have image carousels that get populated via custom-post-types utilizing featured images.

I have titles and headers being populated via custom-post-types and etc... That's all in the index file.

I want to create a pure blog (i.e. news style subsection of the site that aggregates latest blog posts on the www.domain.com/blog, has widget areas that post related content, comment sections, etc etc...) as a subfolder of the landing page.

I was thinking that I would create a new instance of wordpress and put it in a subdirectory of the domain called blog. Obviously this is not an optimal solution.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to do another install of wordpress. Just create a separate template and go from there.

These two links should get you started:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: I see. To be clear: would I treat the "homepage" of the blog as a new template, and populate that template with get_posts() methods for each post? How about the stylesheets? How would I get each particular template to call a particular stylesheet to get styled? Would I just write my rules in the same stylesheet as well?

Comment: Exactly, so you would probably have 2 template files.  One for the "homepage" of the blog that shows multiple posts and maybe an excerpt from each post.  Then you would want a second template for the individual blog posts.  The easiest way to accomplish this was be to have a file named "blog_home_template.php" and then you can create the file "single.php" which is the template file for individual posts.

Comment: If you're going to use "single.php" though, make sure that the rest of your site is built using pages and not posts.  Otherwise, those posts will also be displayed via single.php.

This link has a ton of info on the different files that you can use in a Wordpress theme and their purpose. 

[link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)